# Magento 2 - Disable the compare function in admin panel

Tags: magento2, module, compare

Is there a way to disable the compare function in admin panel?

Comment: Can you add more information, what you exactly want?

Comment: I want to remove the compare list in the navigation bar and also the "add to compare list" button in the product grid. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 2.1 theres no way to disable the compare functionality in the Backend.

The only thing you can do is via the theme:

In your `Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml` of your theme you need the following code to remove the sidebar:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
     </body>
</page>
```

On top of that you need `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` with the following code to remove the link on the product page:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
     </body>
</page>
```

Then to remove the compare link from the product list you need to edit `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` and remove/comment the compare lines.

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.0 but I will have a try on your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Tried in 2.0. It works!

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps you @zzpaul so it help other community members